# Only display first instance of event for each unique person

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, duplicates, min, group

I have a table below (that also has several other columns, but for the purpose of this example, I'll exclude them) where I only want to include the very first instance for each person (unique_id) by date, which is in DATETIME format.

In the past I've used something like:

SELECT
*,
least(min(date_event), min(date_event)) as min_date
FROM
table
GROUP BY
unique_id ,issue, date_event, age_at_event

However, this is still returning multiple records for each person, rather than just the very first instance?

| unique_id | issue | date_event | age_at_event |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | issue_a | 2016-04-01T00:00:00 | 6 |
| 1234 | issue_a | 2016-04-01T00:00:00 | 6 |
| 1234 | issue_b | 2018-04-01T00:00:00 | 8 |
| 5678 | issue_a | 2019-09-01T00:00:00 | 2 |
| 5678 | issue_a | 2021-09-01T00:00:00 | 4 |
| 65431 | issue_c | 2019-09-01T00:00:00 | 1 |
| 1234 | issue_a | 2022-09-01T00:00:00 | 12 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [qualify](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#qualify_clause) function to implement what you're looking for.
With the sample data you provided the following query:

```
select  *
from sample_data
qualify row_number() over (partition by unique_id order by date_event) = 1
```

produces this:
[image]